# Annotations on mapView not showing immediately

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I want to display about 600 annotations based on coordinates that I decode from JSON.  I call the following code to determine and add the annotations (it is called by a function in viewDidLoad(), I have not shown the API code, but I know it works).  All the annotations are determined correctly, however when the initial map appears, no annotations are shown.  They are only shown when I pan the map or zoom.  I would like to show them when the map opens up initially, what am I missing?

```
session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if let data = data
        {
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(TideStations.self, from: data)
                self.tideStations = result.stations
                print("\(result.stations.count) Tide Stations successfully loaded")
                for station in self.tideStations {
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.title = station.properties.name
                    let lattitude = CLLocationDegrees(station.geometry.coordinates[1])
                    let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(station.geometry.coordinates[0])
                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude)
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error while stations parsing: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
```

Update 1:

I'm pretty sure that the issue is due to the ordering and possibly asynchronous nature of the API call I am making.  Could it be that the map is rendered, then in viewDidLoad() the API is called to find the annotation data and the annotations made - however the map is not refreshed with the annotations until I pan or zoom?

Update 2:

After doing a lot more digging, I have confirmed that the issue is due to my lack of understanding of asynchronous processing.  I added the following code to the function that adds the annotations to the map:

```
func showTideStationsOnMap() -> Void {
    if tideStations.count > 0 {
        for station in self.tideStations {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = station.properties.name
            let lattitude = CLLocationDegrees(station.geometry.coordinates[1])
            let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(station.geometry.coordinates[0])
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("No tide stations to show")
    }

}
```

The DispatchQue.main.async resolves the problem, I assume by bringing the drawing from a background task to a foreground task.  My knowledge of async processes is not great still.  Can anyone recommend a good (for a newbie) article to help me understand it?

Answer (score 0):

`iOS` manages it like that. It wants to avoid having a `MapView` with lots of `Annotations` overlaying each other. So it prioritize pins and shows higher priority pins.

Then when you `zoom` in the screen other pins would show up.

[Map View does not show all annotations at first](https://medium.com/@hashemi.eng1985/map-view-does-not-show-all-annotations-at-first-9789d77f6a3a)

Comment: Thanks and an interesting article.  However, it appears to refer to IOS prioritizing and not showing annotations to avoid "overcrowding" of annotations (my word).  However, at first, none of my annotations are shown - not even a prioritized subset to avoid overcrowding.

Comment: I would rather suggest you to Zoom Manually for particular scale once the initial map loading is done.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot more digging, I have confirmed that the issue is due to my lack of understanding of asynchronous processing. I added the following code to the function that adds the annotations to the map:

```
func showTideStationsOnMap() -> Void {
if tideStations.count > 0 {
    for station in self.tideStations {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = station.properties.name
        let lattitude = CLLocationDegrees(station.geometry.coordinates[1])
        let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(station.geometry.coordinates[0])
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
} else {
    print("No tide stations to show")
}
```

}